# DISTINCT in a SQL Server 2005 query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How can I add a distinct to the following query :

```
SELECT TOP(30) X.ID ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Create DESC) AS LIMIT 
FROM X  INNER JOIN Y ON X.ID = Y.ID
```

as for now I get a lot of multiple records

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(30) X.ID, X.CREATE FROM X  INNER JOIN Y ON X.ID = Y.ID
)
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Create DESC) AS LIMIT
FROM CTE
```

You must insert CREATE in your query